# "<?" is being displayed as "&lt;?" in a System.Xml.Linq.XText object

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

In C#, when adding a `"<?"` to an `System.Xml.Linq.XText` value property, the XML string output is being displayed as `"&lt;?"` rather than `"<?"`.

How can I add `"<?"` to an `System.Xml.Linq.XText` value property such that the string output is `"<?"`?

Comment: I don't think Linq-toXml allows to generate invalid XML... Why do you need that/what you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` is the encoded verison of `<`.
`<` cannot be inside an XML Tag, because it has a special meaning (openig of a new Tag).
So everything is fine and will get properly read when you read in the XML again.

Comment: While correct it probably not going to help OP who likely tries to create processing instruction (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

If you really want to add `<?` to the `XText`, the `<` *must* be escaped by the `&lt;` entity; otherwise, you would make the xml corrupt.

However, if you actually want to add a process instruction to the XML such as `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystyles.xsl"?>`, then do it like this:

```
var myXml = new XDocument();
var proc = new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"mystyles.xsl\"");
myXml.Add(proc);
```